# Prove $|f(z)| \leq e^{|z|}$ for a complex, analytic $f$ with $|f^{(k)}(0)| \leq 1$ for any $k$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof, laurent-series

> Let $f: \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$ be an analytic function in $\Bbb{C}$ for which we know $|f^{(n)}(0)| \leq 1, \forall n\in\Bbb{N}$. Prove that, for any $z \in \Bbb{C}$, we have $$|f(z)| \leq e^{|z|}$$

Having that information about all derivatives of $f$ in conjunction with having an exponential function in the inequality I want to prove, got me thinking I could follow this path:

Given that $f$ is analytic in $\Bbb{C}$, $f$ has a Laurent series, centered at $0$, that converges for any $z$. Thus we have

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nz^n$$

Furthermore, we know that

$$c_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} \implies |c_n| \leq \frac{1}{n!}$$

With this in mind we can proceed as follows:

$$|f(z)| = \left|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nz^n\right| \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |c_nz^n| = \\ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |c_n||z|^n \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{|z|^n}{n!} = e^{|z|}$$

which concludes the proof. I am not exactly sure, however, that my starting point is right. That is, I do not know if I can assume from the get-go that there is a Laurent series with convergence radius $+\infty$.

I would appreciate alternative approaches to this problem - if anyone finds any - and considerations about the correctness of mine.

Comment: Isn't it the definition of analytic?

Comment: if a complex function is analytic at every point of $\mathbb C$, it is called Entire, and every entire function is represented by a power series with infinite radius of convergence.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function

Comment: @Exodd therefore my reasoning is correct, right?